# Black screen appears on maximizing and minimizing flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

[image]

is it a rendering issue?
it is happening even after building the app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40068) in the Windows embedding of Flutter.