# Flutter Windows Desktop app gets stuck on white screen after msix installation

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-channel, flutter-release

**Background**

I just developed my first flutter desktop app for a windows machine. The app is working fine while developing/debugging it, but I am trying to test it as an application in release mode.

**What’s done**

1. I created an msix  using pub msix.
2. For signing, I have tried both my
   own certificate and the test certificate that comes with msix
   packages by default.
3. I have tried both stable and beta channels.

**Actual Problem**

When I install the app on the other system (or even on the actual system where I debugged the app). I can install the msix setup successfully I can see my app listed in the apps, but when I try to open it, it is stuck on a blank/white screen. There is no UI rendered. And if I try to maximize the window, it goes to App not responding state.
Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Update / New Finding**

After going through the links provided by [Yehuda Kremer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69173446/1074884) and pulling my hair for a few days, I found the answer in this tweet
https://twitter.com/FilledStacks/status/1436280577439715338?s=20

So the main issue is that app is using some absolute paths that don't work on other machines (after release)

1- My app was using a database, so I have made sure that that database path is relative to the application document directory.
2- Now the build is also referring to some dependencies and their paths are also absolute. I have noticed a flag `CMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY` in the `cmake_install.cmake` but that flag is not being set anywhere.

Here is the log of `flutter build windows -v`
https://pastebin.com/LAeshUMY

-- Now I am looking for a proper way to convert all the paths to relative so that the build is ready for installation on different machines, instead of local installation only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The main problem was that the app was looking for some dependencies and it was unable to find them. As mentioned [here](https://twitter.com/FilledStacks/status/1436280577439715338?s=20).

The reason for not finding that in release mode can be one of the following,

- You are using some dll (package that depends on a dll) that is available on a specific path in your system, but when you are release the app that (absolute) path is not valid anymore.
- You are adding some asset with absolute path (that is only applicable to your system).

**Solution:**

- If it is a dll, you should be adding that to the release folder. In my case it was sqlite3.dll
- If it is some other asset then you should always use the relative path.

Comment: I needed Microsoft staff to tell me this one!  Your research and google are appreciated.  Is there a way to file a bug on the sqlflite package?  This is not right.

Comment: For distribution, I would get the dll from the source rather than dropping in an existing sqlite3.dll    Here is the link  https://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: could you please explain how to and where to add this file. Im using inno setup

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned msix package, let see if the problem is in the app or in the packaging process

run `flutter build windows` without the `flutter pub run msix:create`, then run the created .exe file to see if its work.

btw this issue mention here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74507

and here (the 'maximizing' problem): [Black screen appears on maximizing and minimizing flutter desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600844/black-screen-appears-on-maximizing-and-minimizing-flutter-desktop-app)