# Flutter windows desktop application showing black screen on application launch

Tags: flutter

Flutter windows desktop application showing black screen on application launch

I am try to run windows desktop application in windows 64bit system but application showing black screen on application launch. please help me out

Comment: Click on this link , It will be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127335/flutter-windows-desktop-app-gets-stuck-on-white-screen-after-msix-installation